# c++ mangled function not working in Module Definition File

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, dllexport

**Problem Summary**

The function symbol I've placed in the exports section of module definition file "?Add@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z" is being exported as "?Add" .

**What I'm trying to do**

I want to use DLL redirection to intercept function calls and I'm having some problems with regards to interecepting C++ functions. I'm using the approach specified in https://dl.packetstormsecurity.net/papers/win/intercept_apis_dll_redirection.pdf where I create a DLL with the same name as the one I want to intercept and having it placed in the same directory as the executable.

For my specific case, I'm trying to intercept the MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Add function (has the symbol ?Add@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z from dumpbin.exe) of a simple DLL example from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx. To do that, I created a module definition file with the following information

**definitions.txt**

```
LIBRARY dll_redirector.dll

EXPORTS
  ?Add@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z=myAdd
```

And here's the dll_redirector.cpp (will build the dll that will be placed on the same folder as the executable). Basically, you can see that myAdd would replace the add function with my own (where it basically does nothing)

**dll_redirector.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"


#pragma comment(linker, "/export:?Divide@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z=RealMath.?Divide@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:?Multiply@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z=RealMath.?Multiply@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:?Subtract@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z=RealMath.?Subtract@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z")


__declspec ( naked ) void myAdd(void)
{
    __asm{
        retn
    }
}
```

When I build the DLL though, dumpbin shows me that it exported "?Add" instead of "?Add@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z" . I suspect this might be because of the @ symbol being interpreted as an ordinal prefix (even though from my understanding, there needs to be a space before the @ symbol for it be interpreted as an ordinal). I've tried double quoting the whole symbol name, and I've also tried putting backslash before @ (it'll export it as ?Add\ instead) . Nothing has been helpful so far and I'm not sure what to do.

**Dump of file dll_redirector.dll**

```
File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for dll_redirector.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    56878868 time date stamp Sat Jan 02 00:20:56 2016
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           4 number of functions
           4 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00011113 ?Add = @ILT+270(?myAdd@@YAXXZ)
          2    1          ?Divide@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z (forwarded to RealMath.?Divide@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z)
          3    2          ?Multiply@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z (forwarded to RealMath.?Multiply@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z)
          4    3          ?Subtract@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z (forwarded to RealMath.?Subtract@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z)

  Summary

        1000 .data
        1000 .idata
        2000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
        4000 .text
       10000 .textbss
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This might be a limitation in the VS2010 linker, as the help for the EXPORTS directive doesn't mention C++ name mangling in the VS2010 version but does in the help entry for the VS2015 version.  Can you try a newer Visual Studio?

Comment: Why do you want to do it via a module file, rather than a `#pragma comment` (which is obviously working)?

Comment: @MartinBonner you're right, there's no need for module file. `#pragma comment(linker, "/export:?Add@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z=myAdd") ` didnt work, but @Alan Stokes suggestion of adding __stdcall to my function so that it creates a trailing @ in the symbol worked `#pragma comment(linker, "/export:?Add@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z=_myAdd@0")`

Comment: @AlanStokes Thanks, the link was helpful. It solved my problem :)